# Saving post meta using the new EntityProvider APIs

Tags: block-editor

According to the announcement on the [Make WordPress Core blog post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/03/02/general-block-editor-api-updates/) it appears that to use post meta on a post things have changed quite a bit.

I'm trying to get a simple block to read and save data from a custom field, and for some reason each time I hit save the data is lost.

I start by registering the custom field in PHP (attached to the `init` hook):

```php
  register_post_meta('ebook', 'main_video', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'single' => true,
    'type' => 'string',
  ));
```

and from the block controls I'm trying to then read and set methods to write into that field as follows:

```js
const postType = useSelect((select) => select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType(), []);
  const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp('postType', postType, 'meta');
  const url = meta && meta['main_video'];
  const updateUrl = (newValue) => {
    setMeta({ ...meta, main_video: newValue.url });
  };
```

Both `url` and `updateUrl` variables are then consumed by a gutenberg component:

```
<LinkControl 
   className="wp-block-navigation-link__inline-link-input" 
   value={{ url }} 
   onChange={updateUrl} 
   settings={[]} 
/>
```

If I log the values I can see data coming in and being updated, but as soon as I hit save on the post everything is reset.

The `ebook` post type where this custom field is being registered has support declared for `custom-fields`.

I've followed the [official docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/metabox/meta-block-1-intro/) on this a few times and couldn't get it to work as they describe.

Am I missing a key step here or something's amiss?

Comment: Did you find solution to the problem ?

Comment: At a glance, this all looks alright to me. Have you continued to experience this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am very late at this, but I think the problem here was that at registration code for your custom post type `ebook` (which you did not show) you were missing `supports` for `custom-fields` in args array:

```php
'supports'              => [ 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' ]
```

and also

```php
'show_in_rest'          => true
```

Comment: That supports bit gets me every time. Thanks for your answer, hopefully I will remember this without first having to fall on my face next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your onChange function needs to pass the value, like `onChange={(value) => updateUrl(value)}`